# load xml file into memory

Tags: c#, xml

I need to load a xml file in memory so I can access it several times from different forms.
The xml is in this format:

```
  <Slides>
    <Slide>
      <Name>Name 1</Name>
      <Value>Value 1</Value>
      <Type>Type 1</Type>
    </Slide>
    <Slide>
      <Name>Name 2</Name>
      <Value>Value 2</Value>
      <Type>Type 2</Type>
    </Slide>
  </Slides>
```

I don't want to use a database to store the vars. Is there any other method to store the data in memory?
Right now I'm using a txt file for each slide and streamreader, which I'm sure is not the best option.

EDIT:
I added this code, but will I be able to get the slides every time without reading the xml file again?

```
        var slides = from s in XElement.Load("slides.xml").Elements("Slide")
                      select s;
        foreach (var slide in slides)
        {
            //code
        }
```

Comment: If the data are static this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2820420/600559

Comment: Though there are exceptions, databases are _typically_ used for persistent storage (on disk), not in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the XDocument Load method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx

i think it is better to use XDocument than the XmlDocument... but it depends on your requirements...

The XDocument is more memory optimized than the XmlDocument, and i think they both are easy for use (for getting values from the xml)

Comment: and is the data stored in memory so I can use it whenever I want while the application is open ? or do I have to use the XElement.Load everytime I wanna get the data?

Comment: @KendallHildebrandt As long as you keep that instance of `XDocument` around, you only need to load it once.

Comment: Yea, you can do that, but i would save the whole XElement so i won't limit myself for something else - var xDocument = XDocument.Load("slides.xml");

Answer (score 1):

See the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class. The Load() method does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to save the xml file in your project file or your hard disk.Then only you can load the xml file in code behind.
You can create [xml file dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705461/need-an-approach-to-generate-xml-dynamically/10958521#10958521).it will be much better.

```
using System.Xml;

    XmlDocument myxml = new XmlDocument();
    myxml.Load("D:/sample.xml");//Load you xml file from you disk what you want to load
    string element_1 = myxml.GetElementsByTagName("Name")[0].InnerText;
    string element_2 = myxml.GetElementsByTagName("Value")[0].InnerText; 
    string element_3 = myxml.GetElementsByTagName("Value")[0].InnerText;
    string element_4 = myxml.GetElementsByTagName("Name")[1].InnerText;
    string element_5 = myxml.GetElementsByTagName("Value")[1].InnerText; 
    string element_6 = myxml.GetElementsByTagName("Value")[1].InnerText;
```

Try this program it will help you.

Comment: I think this is a very dirty code especially that you haven't used a loop. What if I have 1000 records? shall I add [i] manually ?

Comment: I just posted for what you asked as question.If you need that kind of code, ask me i'll send you full code with loop...